# Three.js: Glass Material Glitches

Tags: three.js, rendering

I have a bunch of OBJ models containing glass materials. Some of these models render just fine, whereas some have strange glitches when dealing with glass materials. By default I have THREE.DoubleSide turned on for faces, but it seems that for transparent materials it's not a good idea. When I switch to THREE.FrontSide, glass materials look OK, but other materials lose faces. For now, the only obvious solution is to deal with materials separately using THREE.FrontSide for glass materials and THREE.DoubleSide for all other materials. Are there any better solutions?

[image]

Comment: For what is DoubleSided needed? Can those mashes be fixed?

Comment: To expand on J. van Langen's comment: if you need doublesided for a model to show all it's faces, it's not "properly modeled" (i.e. if a 3rd party 3D artist sends you models like this, you'd ask them to fix this and do a better job in the future). If fixing the models is not an option, your approach of splitting material handling for transparent v.s. opaque materials seems the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification! All these models with glass were taken from promotional bundle by one well-known company. THREE.DoubleSide is vital for these models, because otherwise some faces completely dissapear. I'll try to fix the models myself using Blender.